# Highcharts null endpoints flush with chart sides

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to connect `null` endpoints to the sides of the chart (both left and right). In the image below, I want the purple line to connect all the way to the right side of the chart.

[image: high charts graph]

The data point for the purple line are (in reverse order):

```
data: [null,null,null,null,null,null,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200]
```

I can successfully connect `null`s by using `connectNulls` (shown below). Notice on the chart, there are 3 points missing on the blue line around 10/9 and the points connect.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        pointPlacement: "on",
        connectNulls: true
    }
},
```

I have also tried using a combination of the following on `xAxis`:

- `minPadding`
- `maxPadding`
- `startOnTick`
- `endOnTick`

None of the above work. Is there a Highcharts option that I am overlooking? Or how can this be accomplished with a custom function?

Comment: please put code on jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ERFZj/1/

Comment: if first data is null. from where it should be start ?

Comment: The data is reversed using `reversed: true`... I want it to "start" where the last non-null value is. So it should just continue flat at 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   //function for making own data set
   function makeDataSet(d) {   
        var l = d.length, i, isFirstNull = false;

        if(d[0] == null) {
           isFirstNull = true;
        }

         for(i = 0; i < l; i++) {
              if(isFirstNull) {
                 if(d[i] != null) {
                     d[0] = d[i];
                     isFirstNull = false;
                 }
              }
          }
        return d;

   }

      $(function () {

        var data1 = [null,null,null,null,null,null,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200]; //data1

        var data2 = [100,100,null,null,null,null,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]; //data1

         makeDataSet(data1);
         makeDataSet(data2);

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'spline'
        },
        xAxis: {
            reversed: true,
        },
        plotOptions: {
                series: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        pointPlacement: "on",
                        connectNulls: true
                }
        },            
        series: [{
            name: 'Data 1',
            data: data1
        },
        {
            name: 'Data 2',
            data: data2
        }]
    });
});
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/peFeg/)

Comment: That is very close to what I am looking for but is there a way to hide that "point" since technically there is no real data for it?

Comment: Yes just that first point (which reversed is the last point). Literally hide the "point" ... Screenshot - http://d.pr/i/EZ8x

Answer (score 0):

to connect null points, the null values should be in between two values like below

```
data: [200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,null,null,null,null,null,null,400]
```

then it will connect 200 and 400 through nulls.

in your data there is no point to be connected after null so it cannot go ahead.

try it it will work

Comment: I don't want a value at the end. I want it to continue with `null` as the last point. Please re-read the question.

Comment: it is a simple thing, when you say connectNulls: true, it will try to connect nulls between two points, same like drawing a line between two ponts, the only difference is null is in between, now in your case it starts connecting nulls but there is no end point for it to know where to connect through these nulls, so if you want nulls in the end without a data point after it then you will have the line only till the last data point i.e the one before nulls.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are saying. I understand what `connectNulls` does. I want make sure any `null` points at the end get continued from the last point with a value

Comment: i've seen your fiddle in that the data is first series also should be same like the second one, updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ERFZj/3/

Comment: You just added a "1" as the first value. That is not what I am looking for.

Comment: that '1' will help to build the line through the nulls, in your first series data it has got a starting point and then nulls no ending point to connect, this 1 will mark the ending, without ending or starting points you cannot connect nulls